# How to know which process is the one I am running from task manager?

Tags: python, flask, process, web-development-server, taskmanager

I was doing a flask application and there was a problem that the code I write isn't getting executed. Instead of my code getting executed, it executes an older version of the code.

I searched for a solution in stackoverflow and found out the reason for this problem is that there are other python or vscode processes running in the background and they are the ones getting executed instead. The solution for this problem is to disable or kill those other running processes from the task manager and everything will be ok. The problem is that there are lots of running processes and I don't know which ones should I delete and which process is the one I should keep and not disable it.
Here is a picture of the processes in task manager:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just kill all active instances of "Python" by right clicking on them then choosing "End Task" from the context menu that will appear after that.

Comment: Won't that disable my program or even any program using python?

Comment: @yassin-walaa I don't think as you will be terminating the "Python" process that is launched by Visual Studio Code (or is a child of that process)

Comment: What about the vs code processes? What should I do with them especially that when I ran the code the next day, the python processes didn't appear in task manager and only the vs code processes appeared?

Comment: @yassin-walaa You will have to run them manually like you did before.